# Correct way to set webkit value with javascript

Tags: javascript, css, webkit

I can normally use the syntax:

```
element.style.styleName = someValue
```

Such as:

```
element.style.top = "20px"
```

But the following bugs because of the "-"

```
element.style.-webkit-user-select = "initial"
```

What is the correct way to handle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
element.style['-webkit-user-select'] = 'initial';
```

In JavaScript, `foo.bar` and `foo['bar']` are equivalent. If the former would cause a syntax error, you can always fall back on the latter.